# Array Creation out of a class that used generics

Tags: java, arrays, generics, creation

Its my first question on that site!
I' ve done my research but nothing really works...

So, here is the problem, it has to do with Java Generic Array creation:

```
class HashArray<K,V>{

  class HashNode<K,V>{
...
}


HashNode[] array;

HashArray(int size){

ArrayList<HashNode> arrayM = new ArrayList<HashNode>(size);

array = arrayM.toArray(array);                         // pinned Line

}

}
```

and there is a NullPointerException in the pinned Line.
If I try something like:

```
array = new HashNode[size];
```

I get a `Generics Array Creation error`.

I need an Array out of HashNodes because I am only allowed to make the project with arrays.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `HashNode[] array;` is uninitialized. You pass `array` as a paremeter in your pinned line. If you pass `null` to `toArray()` it will throw the NPE.

Comment: is there a way to initialise it? given that you cannot create object?

Comment: `HashNode[] array = new HashNode[0];`

Comment: it also returns the "generic array creation" error:

CacheStr.java:110: error: generic array creation
                        HashNode array = new HashNode[0];
                                         ^

Comment: the first "HashNode" has [] also

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues here. First, an inner class (`HashNode`) has an implicit reference to an instance of its declaring class (`HashArray`). Therefore, it's in the scope of its declaring class's type parameters. You should not redeclare the type parameters `K` and `V` for `HashNode`, because that's hiding the outer ones:

```
class HashArray<K, V> {

    class HashNode {
        //K and V still have meaning in here
    }

    ...
}
```

Either that, or make `HashNode` a static nested class to simplify things for yourself:

```
class HashArray<K, V> {

    static class HashNode<K, V> {
        //no implicit reference to an outer HashArray
    }

    ...
}
```

Getting to the array creation: arrays of concrete parameterized types cannot be created. See Angelika Langer's generics tutorial for an [explanation on why](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Can%20I%20create%20an%20array%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20concrete%20instantiation%20of%20a%20parameterized%20type?). In short, generics and arrays are like oil and water and you should just use collections.

The best solution is to just use a `List<HashNode>` instead. You're already starting with one anyway:

```
List<HashNode> nodeList = new ArrayList<HashNode>(size);
```

Or if you make `HashNode` a static class:

```
List<HashNode<K, V>> nodeList = new ArrayList<HashNode<K, V>>(size);
```

Note that in Java 7, the RHS can just be `new ArrayList<>(size)` in both cases.

---

For completeness of my answer only, if you really insisted on keeping the array, you would need to use an unchecked cast:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashNode[] array = (HashNode[])new HashArray<?, ?>.HashNode[size];
```

Or if `HashNode` was made static:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashNode<K, V>[] array = (HashNode<K, V>[])new HashNode<?, ?>[size];
```

But this would be inherently unsafe and **should not be done**.

Comment: thanks for your full response! Really appreciated! The problem is that I need to use only arrays. I could make a binary tree or something avoiding them, but after research I have found out that the best way to make this project neat is a Hash Array. So I need to implement generic hashing (all Objects have hashCode()) with only arrays. This is the deal. Using a Collection would have been a piece of cake, I agree, but I am not allowed.

Comment: After the Edit you made it perfect!

Comment: @user2007447 Okay but I can't overstate that that isn't a safe solution. I encourage you to read the linked article to understand why. Since this sounds like an assignment, I'll leave it up to you to clarify what to do with your professor. Feel free to ask her/him and even point to this post.

Comment: "should not be done" I disagree with this. The reason for disallowing creating an array of parameterized type is very obscure and not relevant in 99% of the time in normal situations.

Comment: @newacct Regardless of whether that's true, there's no reason not to just use a generic collection 99% of the time in normal situations.